# Anonymous XML Elements

Tags: xml, naming-conventions

I'm working on a piece of code that needs to be able to encode an arbitrary array to its XML representation.

The problem seems to be that, besides a numeric index, array items do not have an identifier. This is a problem because XML does not have a concept of anonymous elements as far as I'm aware.

Basically, I'd like to do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <array>
        <>first item</>
        <>second item</>
        <!-- ... -->
        <>last item</>
    </array>
</root>
```

Given the fact that XML names cannot be empty nor numeric, what's the next best thing?

(Right now, I'm using each item's index number prefixed with an underscore as the element name.)

**EDIT**

I ended up choosing the generic term "item" as the element name for each array entry.

```
<array>
    <item>first item</item>
    <!-- ... -->
    <item>last item</item>
</array>
```

While technically not anonymous, I feel like this is abstract enough to consider those entries anonymous.

Comment: Name an entry in an array "entry"?

Comment: Maybe I will. Having variable element names somehow seems to make things even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry just reread the question. If you want it  anonymous the just create the tag as what ever. Or if you are reconstituting these xmls back into arrays come up with a name that no one would ever use and link that to be nothing in your code

For final answer

Use attributes to capture indexes. Such as

```
<array>
    <item aindex="1">first item</item>
    <item aindex="2"> second item</item>
</array>
```

Comment: To be honest, I felt like that was a pretty good answer. I was just waiting to give other people a chance to post some suggestions.

Comment: Okay I restored the original answer. But to be honest it isn't anonymous if you are capturing index data

Comment: I think I'll use the "item" name, but discard the index number. It doesn't completely satisfy my definition of an anonymous element, but I think it'll do.